# Limpar coluna do database de tempo em tempo

Tags: banco-de-dados

É possível limpar a coluna do database no final do dia/semana/mês?
Tenho um código que registra a quantidade de atendimentos que um funcionário realiza. Por exemplo: no fim do dia ele realizou 17 atendimentos, então, no próximo dia o valor deve retornar a zero. Porém, o valor da semana não pode ser zero, pois ele fez 17 atendimentos no dia anterior. E isso deve acontecer para o mês também.
Grato desde já!

Comment: Qual banco de dados?

Comment: MYSQL, mas creio eu que consegui outra forma de fazer isso. Agradeço de qualquer forma!

Comment: Se está querendo fazer isso, provavelmente está tentando solucionar um problema de uma forma não convencional. Esse tipo de informação (quantidade de atendimentos num dia), deve ser originada pela soma dos registros de atendimentos feitos por um atendente no dia e não pelo valor colocado em uma coluna para depois ser zerado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você já registra esse dado, pra que apagar? Dá pra fazer isso usando trigger (precisa detalhar qual banco você está usando). Mas é desperdício de processamento do servidor.

Se for apenas pela exibição do dado ao usuário, você pode resolver isso facilmente em dois passos:

1) Alterar a tabela para gravar a data atual quando o salvamento for feito

2) Realizar uma query no BD utilizando where (e filtrar pelos parâmetros de dia, semana e mês, conforme o caso).

Comment: Realmente, não tinha pensado nisso. Muito obrigado bro :D